# How to Fix Ambiguous Reference to Overloaded apply() method when deserializing Json

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Given the following case class that needs to be serialized/deserialized to/from JSON...

```
import play.api.libs.json
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

trait MyTrait(s1: String, s2: String)

case class MyClass(s1: String, s2: String) extends MyTrait {

  def this(t: MyTrait) = this(t.s1, t.s2)
}

object MyClass {

  def apply(t: MyTrait) = new MyClass(t)

  implicit val myClassJsonWrite = new Writes[MyClass] {
    def writes(c: MyClass): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "s1" -> c.s1,
        "s2" -> c.s2
      )
    }
  }

  implicit val myClassJsonRead = (
    (__ \ 's1).read[String] ~
    (__ \ 's2).read[String]
  )(MyClass.apply _)
}
```

... I always get the following error message:

```
[error] /home/j3d/Projects/test/app/models/MyClass.scala:52: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method apply in object MyClass of type (s1: String, s2: String)models.MyClass
[error] and  method apply in object MyClass of type (t: MyTrait)models.MyClass
[error] match expected type ?
[error]   )(MyClass.apply _)
[error]             ^
```

... why doesn't the compiler infer the right `apply` method? How could I fix this error? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the correct method like this:

```
MyClass.apply(_: String, _: String)
```

The compiler can not infer the correct type because you reference the `apply` method. Because you explicitly reference them the compiler will not make that choice for you.

To make the syntax a bit more readable you can change you companion object definition

```
object MyClass extends ((String, String) => MyClass) {
```

That way you can simply reference the companion object instead of the ambiguous `apply` method

```
implicit val myClassJsonRead = (
  (__ \ 's1).read[String] ~
  (__ \ 's2).read[String])(MyClass)
```